# ODataClient The response payload is a not a valid response payload

Tags: odata

Inner Exception 1:
DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: The response payload is a not a valid response payload. Please make sure that the top level element is a valid Atom or JSON element or belongs to 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/data' namespace.

I am getting a very strange error, when I compile the app it compiles once the odata client goes to the database it then crashes with the above error. I have done some research about this and I can see that it is basically looking for the metadata from the odata request. However, I have supplied it, and when i run the uri in postman it works. So my question is what am i doing wrong?

c#:

```
public const string MetadataDocumentUri = "http://localhost/QuickQuoteApi/odata/$metadata";
```

I get to the controller and it executes fine. Help would be much appreciated

I'm using `Devexpres GridControl` to access the datasource.

```
<dx:WcfCollectionViewSource x:Key="WcfCollectionViewSource" 
                                Culture="en-US" 
                                ContextType="{x:Type QuickQuote:QuickQuoteContainer}" 
                                CollectionViewType="{x:Type ListCollectionView}" 
                                Path="Companies" 
                                ServiceRoot="http://localhost/QuickQuoteApi/odata/">
        <dx:DesignDataManager.DesignData>
            <dx:DesignDataSettings RowCount="5"/>
        </dx:DesignDataManager.DesignData>
    </dx:WcfCollectionViewSource>
</dx:DXWindow.Resources>
<Grid>
    <dxg:GridControl AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource WcfCollectionViewSource}}">
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" ShowTotalSummary="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

I have also added webapi config

```
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmModel edmModel = GetEdmModel();
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("OdataRoute", "odata", edmModel);


        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
            Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None;
    }



        private static Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.Namespace = "QuickQuote";
            builder.ContainerName = "QuickQuoteContainer";

            builder.EntitySet<Address>("Addresses");
            builder.EntitySet<Company>("Companies");
            builder.EntitySet<Connector>("Connectors");
            builder.EntitySet<Contact>("Contacts");
            builder.EntitySet<ContactType>("ContactTypes");
            builder.EntitySet<Coordinate>("Coordinates");
            builder.EntitySet<FromTo>("FromTos");
            builder.EntitySet<Manufacturer>("Manufacturer");
            builder.EntitySet<Nc>("Ncs");
            builder.EntitySet<Position>("Positions");
            builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
            builder.EntitySet<Question>("Questtions");
            builder.EntitySet<Quote>("Quotes");
            builder.EntitySet<Role>("Roles");
            builder.EntitySet<SingleTerminal>("SingleTerminals");
            builder.EntitySet<TotalHeader>("TotalHeaders");
            builder.EntitySet<TotalItem>("TotalItems");
            builder.EntitySet<TotalLabel>("TotalLabels");
            builder.EntitySet<User>("Users");
            builder.EntitySet<Worksheet>("Worksheets");
            builder.EntitySet<WorksheetLabel>("WorksheetLabels");

            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
}
```

Comment: You don't get this error via postman. How are you accessing the dataservice when you do get this error? Manual HTTP request?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're outputting json but the Content-Type in the request is xml